# change style of row in react big calendar

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, calendar, react-big-calendar

I need to make a calendar with events and I decided to use react-big-calendar. But I need to make rows with different style. So each row should be in 30minutes that I did it with timeslots, but I also need to remove default borders and make new border around each four rows . How can I change the style?

[image: r]

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any information on the [npmjs.org](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-big-calendar) site... and since the divs are created dynamically, we can use CSS to get this effect;

relevant CSS:

```
.rbc-timeslot-group:nth-child(1), .rbc-timeslot-group:nth-child(2), .rbc-timeslot-group:nth-child(3), .rbc-timeslot-group:nth-child(23), .rbc-timeslot-group:nth-child(24)
{ background-color: lightpink; }
```

sample [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/big-calendar-demo-g2mu2b)

Comment: Thanks Akber, how can I set border around these four elements, it should apply  for every 4 rows.

Comment: and why did you select children number 23,34 ??

Comment: Hi Hamid, i selected a few rows to signify out-of-work hours... true if you're from south asia ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @akber-iqbal I found my answer, so these styles worked for me, if you can optimize it, you can share it, thank you.

```
 .rbc-day-slot .rbc-time-slot {
  border: unset;
}
.rbc-timeslot-group:nth-child(4n+1),
.rbc-timeslot-group:nth-child(4n+2),
.rbc-timeslot-group:nth-child(4n+3),
.rbc-timeslot-group:nth-child(4n+4)
 {  /* or 4n+1 */
  background-color: #fefefe;
  border-width:0px; 
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border-color:black;
}


.rbc-timeslot-group:nth-child(4n+1)
 { border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

see https://stackblitz.com/edit/big-calendar-demo-jv11jb